# Iterating through values

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to add up all of the values from frequencies. so it would be 0 +.1 being put into cum_freq, then .1 + .2 then so on. Im unsure how to get the frequencies value in my for loop.

```
frequencies = ['a': .1, 'b': .2, 'c': .7]
cum_freq = [0] * 4
cum_freq[0] = 0
for i in range(1, len(cum_freq)):
    cum_freq[i] = cum_freq[i-1] + "how do I get the i-1 value from frequencies?"
```

Comment: I guess that `frequencies` is meant to be a `dict`: `dict`s are delimited with `{...}` not `[...]`.

Comment: The third line is superfluous. `cum_freq = [0] * 4` is equivalent to `cum_freq = [0,0,0,0]`. `cum_freq[0] = 0` means 'replace the first of those four zeros with zero.

Comment: You talk about the 'i - 1 value from frequencies'. `frequencies` is (I guess) meant to be a dictionary with letters as keys, so you can't use `i-1` as a key. Dictionaries are unordered, so if you mean to use `i-1` as an "index" in the dictionary, it won't make any sense either.

Comment: Upgrade to Python 3 and take a look at [itertools.accumulate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate). But if you have a lot of data I suggest you use Numpy for this.

Comment: As jacg said, plain dictionaries are unordered (although that will probably change in future versions, since Python 3.6 has "unofficial" unordered dictionaries). So if you want to access dict items in some fixed order you generally need to maintain some separate list of keys. Another possibility is to use consecutive integer keys, but if you're doing that you might as well just use a list.

Comment: Do you simply want to add up the numeric values from the dictionary? Does the order matter?